# Jetpack Composable Not updating text fields unless the "apply changes and restart activity" button is clicked while that composable is loaded

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I'm not sure why the EditForm composable is not updating itself. The only way it updates is when I the EditForm composable in loaded int App and the "apply changes and restart activity button" is clicked in Android studio. The data is persisting in viewModel just not sure why not updating. Here are some snippets...

```
class RickAndMortyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _castMember = mutableStateOf<CastMember?>(null)
    val castMember: State<CastMember?> = _castMember

    // Function to update the castMember
    suspend fun updateCastMemberById(cID: Int, db: AppDatabase){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _castMember.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                db.dao.getCastMemberByID(cID)
            }

        }
    }
    fun getCastMember(): CastMember?{
        return castMember.value
    }

}
```

```
@Composable
fun CharacterCard(c:CastMember,db: AppDatabase, navController: NavController){


    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(2.dp)
            .background(color = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.LightGray)
            .border(
                1.dp,
                color = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Black,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            )
    ){
        Column {
            //Text("where is this data going?")
            AsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(
                    LocalContext.current)
                    .data(c.image)
                    .build(),
                contentDescription = c.name
            )
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = c.id.toString())
            Text(text = c.name)
            Text(text = "Species: " + c.species)
            Text(text = "Gender: " + c.gender)
            //Text(text = "Origin: " + c.origin.name)

            // row
            Row(
                modifier= Modifier.padding(start=200.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ){
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_insert),
                    contentDescription = "Insert ${c.name}",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            // insert record in background
                            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                                db.dao.insertCastMember(c)
                                Log.i("INSERTED:", "${c.name} into database" )
                            }

                        }
                )
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_edit),
                    contentDescription = "Edit ${c.name}",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            // go to another screen for editing
                            navController.navigate("edit/${c.id}")
                        }
                )


                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_delete),
                    contentDescription = "Delete ${c.name}",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            // delete record in background thread
                            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                                db.dao.deleteCastMember(c)
                                Log.i("DELETED:", "${c.name} from database" )
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
        }

    }
}

@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun EditForm(cID: Int, db: AppDatabase, viewModel: RickAndMortyViewModel){
    //var castMember by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<CastMember?>(null) }

    var name by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("")}
    var species by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("")}
    var gender by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("")}
    //var cMember by remember { mutableStateOf<CastMember?>(null) }

    Log.i("cID", cID.toString())


    // when cID changes update Cast Member
    LaunchedEffect(cID){
        viewModel.updateCastMemberById(cID,db)
    }

    name = viewModel.getCastMember()?.name.toString()







    Column {
        Log.i("CastMember", "")

        TextField(
            value = name,
            onValueChange = {
                name = it
            },
            label={
                Text("Name")
            }
        )

        TextField(
            value = viewModel.getCastMember()?.species.toString(),
            onValueChange = {
                species = it
            },
            label={
                Text("Species")
            }
        )
        TextField(
            value = viewModel.getCastMember()?.gender.toString(),
            onValueChange = {
                gender = it
            },
            label={
                Text("Gender")
            }
        )
        Button(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        ) {
            Text("Update")
        }
    }

}
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RickAndMortyChallengeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    // get activity context
                    var context: Context = LocalContext.current

                    // fetch api data
                    val rickAndMortyManager: RickAndMortyManager = RickAndMortyManager()

                    // initialize local database
                    val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)

                    // init navController so that we can navigate throughout app
                    val navController = rememberNavController()

                    // define routes
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Destination.Home.route ){
                        composable(Destination.Home.route){
                            CharacterScreen(rickAndMortyManager = rickAndMortyManager, db = db, navController =  navController)
                        }
                        composable("edit/{cID}"){ backStackEntry ->
                            // extract parameters from route
                            var str_cID: String? = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("cID") ?: "nil"
                            var cID = str_cID?.toInt()

                            if (cID != null) {
                                EditForm(cID, db, viewModel = RickAndMortyViewModel())
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //CharacterScreen(rickAndMortyManager,db, navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Dao
interface RickAndMortyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertCastMember(c: CastMember)

    @Delete()
    fun deleteCastMember(c: CastMember)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cast_members WHERE id = :cID")
    fun getCastMemberByID(cID: Int): CastMember

}
```

I'm trying to update records in a database. I'm using compose-navigation to navigate from listing page to form page (for editing) prior to updating record in database. An id is being passed from listing page (character page) to form page where a query is then made against database to retrieve character data - which I had planned on updating prior to saving to database. Problem I'm having is that null are loaded each time I get to form unless I restart the activity in android studio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfUiq.png)

leads to a form page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLJ9A.png)

notice all fields are null, however, when I force recomposition it works as expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orRIc.png)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `LaunchedEffect(true, cID){ viewModel.updateCastMemberById(cID,db) }` Can you try it like this in your edit form screen ?

Comment: same result. Each field is null until I restart activity. It seems that I need a state level variable so that the composable emits a new state (new screen with data).